# Generator and check matrices of Hamming code

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

What is the method to find a generator matrix and a check matrix of a Hamming code?

I'm current trying to find a generator matrix of Ham$(2,3$).

This is how far I have got:

$$n = \frac{q^s - 1}{q - 1} = \frac{3^2 - 1}{3-1} = 4$$

Therefore there are 4 columns and 2 rows of the generator matrix.

So the generator matrix will take the form of \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & ? & ? \\ 0 & 1 & ? & ?\end{bmatrix}

How do I know what the $2 \times 2$ matrix to the right should contain?

Comment: How are you defining Hamming Code?

Comment: @GitGud Ham(s, q)  is a linear q-ary code for which the check matrix has as column representatives vectors of each element of the projective space $\mathbb{P}_{s-1}(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Comment: Do you know how to get a generator matrix from a check matrix?

Comment: Yeah, the identity and $-A^T$ (where A would be question mark $2 \times 2$ matrix). But I've been asked to try and find the generator matrix first and then work out the check matrix from it

Comment: That's odd, considering the check matrix lies in the very definition of Hamming Code. Well, good luck then.

Comment: @GitGud How would I create the check matrix? Would the order of the column matter? Could it be \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 &1 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}
Which could then make the generator matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 \\ 0  &1 & -1 &-1 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0  &1 & 2 &2 \end{bmatrix}$
But that looks wrong

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "mattering". Changing the order of the columns does change the code, but it changes it to an equivalent code, so (in a sense) it doesn't matter. And yes, that's a possible check matrix. Why do you think what you did is wrong?

Comment: @GitGud Oh I understand! There are several Ham$(2,3)$ codes and the question is asking me to find the matrices for just one of them. Is my method okay or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What you did is what I'd do. I doubt there's a better way, but let's see if someone finds one.